# Security - Sessions ( default use - Cookie ) vs. local storage

Tags: php, javascript

I'm not concerned with browser compatibility.

I want to know if I move my state from PHP Controlled ( Server-Side) sessions to the JavaScript Controlled ( Client - Side ) HTML 5 local storage will I gain or loose security.

I think that I would gain security because now instead of having the user identifier residing in a cookie, which is usually a file, or sql database that is easily accessible...it is not inside some sort of internal browser storage. + b.c. it is a newer technology I would hope that more security was designed into it.

Do I gain or loose security by moving from PHP Sessions to JavaScript Local Storage. ( This is for things like user id, page_id, etc, the current state that remains after a reload and longer if needed ).

I have a JavaScript solution I want to replace my PHP Sessions with.  That is why I ask.  I don't care about browser compatibility.

Here is an [informative site](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) on Local Storage.  But Security was not mentioned.

Comment: The localStorage is saved locally, so anyone else who uses the computer can see the localStorage for any website saved.

Comment: Hiro - with sessions, the data is stored on the server; only the session *identifier* is stored locally in a cookie.

Comment: If that were true...how are people implementing Remember Me...they have to store the user_id in some form on the local system?

Comment: @Hiro they usually store the session ID in a long-lasting cookie. Session data is *never* stored locally on the client machine.

Comment: When I set the Cookie Array in PHP where does that data go?

Comment: If you are sure...do you know out of curiosity where it is stored... on the server?

Comment: @Hiro if you store stuff in the `$_COOKIE` array, it is stored locally on the client machine, open for anyone with access to the user's profile on the machine to see. The same goes for JS local storage. If you store it in `$_SESSION`, the data is stored on the server. Only the session ID tying the user to the session is stored locally.

Comment: Re your second question - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: But the same security flaw is present...a user can login as one person...fiddle with the session_id of the Session and become someone else...fiddling with a session_id...equates to fiddling with who you appear to be to the server ?

Comment: @Pekka - Thanks ..can you respond to my last comment please....what is so special about a Locally Saved Session ID as opposed to a Locally Saved User ID.....both identify you to the server?

Comment: @Hiro a session ID usually has an expiry time and/or is tied to an IP address. A user ID does not. Of course, the session ID is the weak point of this storage method but it's infinitely more safe than storing data indefinitely on the local client

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - session_id stored in a cookie is usually a random MD5 hash. Many websites have custom session handlers and they check the MD5 they read from the cookie against other data they collected from the users (such as IP + fingerprint in form of MD5 of their USER_AGENT string and various other data they can get). So in theory, if I guess that your session_id is 123456789 and change it in my cookie, you should be checking for my IP address as well, not just blindly believe that the data provided is valid. That's the basic form of security. Swapping to localStorage does nothing.

Comment: @Pekka - Storage time is not indefinite. This can be set as well.

Comment: @N.B - That is my point, that all of these meauseres can be implemented in JavaScript just as easily - encryption, fingerprinting, and timed deletions...with the one possible added benefit that local storage is more difficult to access than a cookie file or cookie sql data entry

Comment: ....the methods would of course be hidden server side.....but the data stored client side...?

Comment: @Hiro but what if the client's HD breaks? Local storage can make sense in certain situations, but not to increase security of a traditional server-side storage method. If you are worried about session hijacking, there are ways to protect against it - search SO for more info. For example the expiry time; then you can do IP and user agent checks; etc. well-designed sites will also ask for your password *again* before changing anything serious, for the same reason.

Comment: They can't. None of those measures can be implemented in JS. You never want to store anything at client side except some piece of information that you can use to check it against saved data on your server. Remember, every _SINGLE_ thing you save on users's computer - they can (and will) change it.

Comment: @Pekka - If a user's HD breaks...state is lost...but no data is lost....I would not base my design on this case....You can implement Local Storage State same way as you can with Sessions...in the event of a HD failure...Server Side would provide more robust...but I'm just not concerned with this one case.

Comment: @Hiro so you want to store only the session ID in local storage because it is encrypted? I guess that *would* make sense to protect the client against local break-ins, but I don't know whether it is feasible: you would prboably have to build your own data retrieval functions that send the session ID and get all the data (as the ID is not passed along with every request like with cookies).

Comment: @Hiro if you are working on something super classified that needs top-notch security, it may be worth it. But usually, normal cookies in connection with https and short expiry times should be enough.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - what makes you think swapping localStorage for cookie would grant anything? You'd lose the automatic reading and sending of the cookie that browsers do and you'd have to create a function that does it for you. Not to mention that cookies work with SSL if you have any in place, which is the best thing you can do for security to avoid main in the middle types of attacks that would sniff the data some users is sending to your server.

Comment: ...I prefer as much logic on the client as I can get....all my server does is store sql tables...pretty much...soon I hope to find a purely peer to peer solution...but one step at a time...thanks for the input.

Comment: Erm, you won't. At least not with HTTP as it is, unless you can abandon all data integrity and security whatsoever - then you can. You can use built-in databases avail. in modern browsers, that can be your p2p storage layer.. but why on earth create a web app that tries to enforce security by using resources that are visible to the naked eye?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both types of local storage (localStorage and Cookies) use some sort of identifier which is obviously stored on the client.

Both use a hash mechanism to secure it from altering to another user.

Local Storage is more secure then cookies ( see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) ).

And obviously you have to write the session protocols if you want to move your user identifier from cookies to localStorage.

Both can be stolen to fake being another user.  Though less likely with localStorage.

And to make robust you need a fingerprinting technique that will help with above problem.

Comment: However localStorage can be read by XSS. Unlike cookies if you set httpOnly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a JavaScript solution I want to replace my PHP Sessions with.

No. Do not do it. Sessions are stored in the server side. The cookie that is sent out to the browser is typically an identifier for that record. Session stores user-specific data. Almost anything stored on the client side can be easily modified by the user. So if the user modifies the session to point to another user, the security would no longer hold.

LocalStorage is **NOT** for storing sessions. Stick with PHP sessions, or any other session mechanism that is implemented on the server side.

**Update**

> But the same security flaw is present...a user can login as one
>   person...fiddle with the session_id of the Session and become someone
>   else...fiddling with a session_id...equates to fiddling with who you
>   appear to be to the server ?...this would be the same as fiddling with
>   an encrypted user_id in local_storage.

No. Suppose I figure out the algorithm you are encrypting with. And I know of another user say UserB. I encrpyted his username using that algorithm. If I somehow overwrite my localStorage with that encrypted string, I am him now. That is not much possible practically. Think of it as there are 100 users and 128 byte-string is the identifier. Are you sure you would be able to fiddle with it and modify it into another record which exists in the table of sessions?

Comment: But the same security flaw is present...a user can login as one person...fiddle with the session_id of the Session and become someone else...fiddling with a session_id...equates to fiddling with who you appear to be to the server ?...this would be the same as fiddling with an encrypted user_id in local_storage.

Comment: they can fiddle, but, they need to discover another valid session id first. Thats not easy. and no, its not equiv to fiddling with local storage. local storage has no control over the data, serverside has full controll.

Comment: A network eavesdropper could read cookie information and duplicate a session ID.  This is why SSL (i.e. blocking eavesdropping) is *critical* for protecting a user's session.

Comment: Your way of storing in localStorage is only safe till someone finds out the encryption you are using. But when stored in the server it is safe as it is difficult to guess one valid identifier out of trillion(or more) combinations within a specific time period.

Comment: You missing the point...I'm comparing cookies to localStorage...in BOTH cases, when using sessions, the user ID ( hashed of course ) is stored on the client.

Comment: In case of only a reference (to the session; like the session id or something) being stored on the client side, you are correct. What I meant was do not store the actual contents of the session.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is best suited for data that you want to cache on the client in a (more permanent) way then with the regular browser cache. The only way it's "more secure" is if you want to allow the user to work with data that's *never sent to the server*.

If you're worried about session hijacking, the preferred solution would be to use https/ssl and encrypt *all traffic* between you and the client. There's a [general overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) of the problem and solutions on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) (we'd need more information to give you anything much more specific than that, though).

Comment: I'm not worried...I'm comparing cookies to localStorage...for storing a hashed user ID on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't gain or lose security as in most browsers all data set by sites are stored in the same folder