# ionic/angularjs with django csrf works on local server but not working on device

Tags: ios, angularjs, django, ionic-framework, csrf

I am working on [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) with [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) as backend. I tried to post to my server with `$http` as following:

```
$http({
  url: url,
  method: method,
  data: {
    // some data
  }
}).success...
```

Also I set the following in my config:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

I also tried `ngCookies` but `$cookies.csrftoken` does not return anything.

Here is my backend code:

```
class Mark(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # do something
        return Response({
            # something
        })
```

This works perfect when I used ionic local server `ionic serve`, but when I build it on iOS emulator or on my iPhone, csrf 403 appears:

```
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

returned from the server.

Any idea on this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think you need CSRF token when you developing mobile app.

Comment: APIView does not require csrf_token

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think this information will fix your problem you will probably face it later. On iOS cookies are lost when rebooting the application, use window.localStorage to store them.

See answer:
[Can you use cookies in a Cordova application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139365/can-you-use-cookies-in-a-cordova-application#answer-31139648)