# Ionic 2: login via keycloak won't store keycloak cookies

Tags: ionic2, jwt, keycloak

I am building Ionic 2 app and I want to use Keycloak for login/signup.

I have the following situation:

I am on Keycloak login page and when I login, I am redirect back to my app. I would expect that Keycloak will set cookies, but it didn't. I guess it is because of this: [Can you use cookies in a Cordova application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139365/can-you-use-cookies-in-a-cordova-application).

Is there any way how to tell Keycloak to use local storage instead of cookies. Or any other solution?

I am using this [implementation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/fc6d6ff7f7dae7fb25edf052659d18cd8de55a5f/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app) of keycloak & angular 2 colaboration.

Comment: Could you tell how you integrated Keycloak or at-least some link about the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Keycloak there is a [Javascript Adapter](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html) - keycloak.js, it already knows how to work with a Cordova application, it is only necessary to disable the token checking through the iframe.

I created a simple app Ionic2 with Keycloak integration https://github.com/sergeyrolich/ionic2-keycloak