# Ionic 2: login with keycloak

Tags: angular, cookies, ionic2, session-cookies, keycloak

I have **MyApp** - Ionic 2 app and I would like to implement login via **Keycloak** as you can see here [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/fc6d6ff7f7dae7fb25edf052659d18cd8de55a5f/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app).

**MyApp** is runnig on http://localhost:8100/

**Keycloak** server on http://localhost:8080/

Have following scenario:

1. User Access MyApp and press login button.
2. User is redirect to Keycloak page, fills the credentials and press the login.
3. User is redirected back to MyApp:

[image]

Here is the issue:  The MyApp will not store the cookies from Keycloak response ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139365/can-you-use-cookies-in-a-cordova-application)). So I was thinking about catching the redirect from Keycloak, extracting the cookies and storing them into LocalStorage. I don't know how in Angular 2 catch such redirect.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the Keycloak there is a Javascript Adapter - keycloak.js, it already knows how to work with a Cordova application.

Your another question already has an answer, how to work with this js adapter [Ionic 2: login via keycloak won't store keycloak cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297008/ionic-2-login-via-keycloak-wont-store-keycloak-cookies/44385145#44385145)